# calling JSON Service from Objective C with MULTIPLE parameters

Tags: ios, json

I've found code samples for calling a JSON service, but I'm not sure how to add multiple parameters. Could somebody help me out?

My JSON Service is a .NET WCF service `SearchTalent(talentName, agentName, agencyName)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to find out the URL's of the service, not the .Net representation of the service.
I'd suggest you use Restkit to interface with the service once you know the urls. You might want to look into that.